# CoffeeScript chaining functions

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I want to make a chaining function by inheritance the prototype

Every call should use the last chain return

```
Number::plus = (n) ->
    setTimeout =>
        console.log this + n
    ,1000

1.plus(1).plus(8).plus(90)
```

---

Expected:

```
# after 1 sec
> 2
# after 1 sec
> 10
# after 1 sec
> 100
```

Comment: You cannot return a value from an asynchronous method (`setTimeout`). Why are you using it?

Comment: @Caffeinated.tech That's just an example to explain there is an async stuff inside, actually i am doing a chaining animation, every step should start after the last step.

Comment: I would suggest that you use a `Promise` library for chaining async method calls together. [Bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html) is a good example. You can use native promises in Firefox/Chrome, but they aren't supported across all browsers.